Help with partitions disks
I only have one hard drive and I had partitioned everything, I left the home with more space but everything I installed is also being saved in root and I no longer have any space left since by default I set 25 or 30 GB, how can I occupy the partition with more space and free up space in the root to update Ubuntu
enter image description here

See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier.
It explains where things go. Departing from the Standard places one at risk of becoming broken and unsupportable. You must boot from a Live USB (your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode) to adjust your disk's partitions.

Your / (root) is just too small for Ubuntu now. I use Kubuntu and do not allow snaps and use 16GB. But have seen users with 20GB of snaps only. Also your swap is not very large. Default swap is 2GB as a swap file. If using a swap partition 4.1GB is often suggested.

Looks like a classic Windows power-user mistake of over-partitioning based on reading too much old advice and relying on Windows skills that simply don't apply. Back up your data, re-partition based on your experience (hint: The installer defaults to single partition. Try it), and then reinstall.

Don't forget packages have set locations they'll install to (this varies on type of package of course; most like deb & snap give little choice, others like appimage or compile from source give more choice) and if you didn't specify a specific drive/partition for that directory everything you didn't specify a specific location to will end up in /. Myself I need >32GB of space in /, but space requirements vary on how we use our systems, what software we add to it etc (and package type plays a part too; snap/flatpak/appimage tend to use more disk space)
